# PLSQL table insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have table1 which has col1, col2, col3 ... colN

I have table2 which is a param table and a param value has comma separated data like (`PQR3,XYZ5,ABC`)

Now I have a table 3 which has 2 columns X, Y in which I have to insert data, like so:

```
If col1 || col2 = any of those comma separated values . i.e (PQR3,XYZ5,ABC)
Then insert into t3  values (col3 in X) and 'YES' in Y
Else insert into t3 values  col3 in X  and 'NO' in Y
```

I have tried using comma separation to decode (`instr(),YES,NO`)
but it does not work.

Comment: Hi Barun, please add a clear statement of what you want to achieve and the reason as first line of the question. Additionally, add code examples using the correct code widget.

Comment: @RafaelGorski please do not add trivial edits to the review queues. While correct tagging is important, this question has serious formatting problems that should have been addressed in your edit.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place. Read up on database normalization

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand table1 and table2 connection. But instr usage can be like below.

```
for rec in (select * from table2 t)loop
  if INSTR(rec.param_value, ',') > 1 then
    --insert table3 YES
  else
    --insert table3 NO
  end if;
end loop;
```